# How to do conditional from an array object that showing value is null using v-if

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have some array like:

{
'size': null
}

i try using size.length / this.size.length still doesn't work because the length is still there when size: null

```
<div class="form-group" v-if="size">
    <select class="custom-
        <option value="" v-for="s in size" :key="s.id">                            
            {{ s.size }}
       </option>
    </select>
</div>

data(){
     return{
        size: null,
    }
},
```

i would like to not show the form group when size is null using v-if

and i want the object is still there ( not using an empty object )

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 of 2 things use `!!` Double negative operator which will convert it into a boolean, or you can simply write `v-if="size !== null`

Comment: where to put '!!' ?

Comment: `v-if = "!!size"`